# Problem with the User and Group inside a container

Tags: docker, uid

**Preliminary**

First, a preliminary. When running a docker container with a volume mapped to some part of the host, the user inside the docker container is usually root, so for files generated by the container, the Host cannot edit, modify or delete them. To solve this some people (including the one who created the image I am using) recommends using `-u`

**The Situation**

I have a Docker image (built by a different person in a different machine)

This Docker image assumes the user is going to be a user with id 1000

**The problem**

When a person who is the only user of a Host machine (and whose user id is 1000) runs the image, there is no problem. However, in my case I am the second user of this Host so my user id is 1001. So I have  the following:

In the Host I do `cat /etc/passwd` and I get several users including:

```
firstuser:x:1000:1000:firstluser,,,:/home/firstuser:/bin/bash

myself:x:1001:1001:My Name,,,:/home/myself:/bin/bash
```

Then :

**CASE 1** I run the container with

```
docker run -it --rm -u 1001:1001  -v /a/path:/another/path image  /bin/bash
```

because doing `id -u` and `id -g` gives me 1001.(I am the second user after all)

Doing this causes that

```
groups:cannot find name for group ID 1001
```

then my user becomes `"I have no name!"` and when I do `cat/etc/passwd`  I get

`originaluser:x:1000:1000::/home/originaluser:bin/bash`   <---- here there are not ,,,

so obviously my user (1001) does not exist which causes a lot of problems.

To solve this I tried

**CASE2**  I run the container with

```
docker run -it --rm -u 1000:1000  -v /a/path:/another/path image  /bin/bash
```

which does not cause the previous error, and now even though I am `myself` but run the Docker image as `firstuser`, in the container I am `originaluser` (since both are 1000)

Doing the `cat /etc/passwd` I can see

```
originaluser:x:1000:1000::/home/sensetime:bin/bash
```

and as predicted my user is `originaluser`.

I should be happy but, this also causes problems!

Later on the program inside the container tries to create a file (with user 1000) but since it is mapped and the user owner is 1001 this creation fails.

What is a good way to prevent all these problems and be able to synchronize the user in the host with the user in the container?

Comment: What is your use case where a user on the host needs to directly edit a data file managed by a container process?  The "I have no name" message should mostly be a cosmetic issue in the unusual case of running an interactive shell in a container.

Comment: @David Maze I can't speak to the op's use case, but I/O is faster on a mounted directory than the docker's virtual memory. The performance benefit is one reason the docker may need access to files on the host machine.

Answer (score 2):

I recently discovered [fixuid](https://github.com/boxboat/fixuid) which may solve most of you problems.

The uid/gid in a container cannot (or is not expected to) match the ones on your host.

The `fixuid` *setuid* go binary I linked above can solve this by changing the uid/gid of the user in docker to match the one you configured.

For instance:

Host: uid/gid/name=1001/1001/kansai
Guest user: uid/gid/name=1000/1000/user

If you had add the `fixuid` binary in you container (build phase) then you can run:

```
docker run --rm -it -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v /a/path:/another/path image fixuid /bin/bash
```

You can also set `fixuid` in an entrypoint so it will be easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!. Actually the person who built the image did include fixuid in the entrypoint but I got the "fixuid: already ran on this system; will not attempt to change UID/GID" error. I wrote a question about this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64313676/why-is-fixuid-refusing-to-change-the-uid-gid