# Why is fixuid refusing to change the UID/GID?

Tags: docker, file-permissions

I have a situation similar to the question that got answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45518782/4451521).

In the answer, it is proposed to use fixuid in the docker image so as to (and I cite)

> We have created a workaround for this issue that changes a Docker
> container's user/group and file permissions that were set at build
> time to the UID/GID that the container was started with at runtime.
>
> The project and install instructions are at:
> https://github.com/boxboat/fixuid
>
> Example:
>
> - Docker container was built using user/group dockeruser:dockergroup as UID/GID 1000:1000.
> - Host is running as UID/GID 1001:1002.
> - Image is run with docker run -u 1001:1002. fixuid will:
> - change dockeruser UID to 1001
> - change dockergroup GID to 1002
> - change all file permissions for old dockeruser:dockergroup to 1001:1002
> - update $HOME inside container to dockeruser $HOME
> - now container and host UID/GID match and files created in the container on host mounts will match.
>
> It can run as the ENTRYPOINT or as part of a startup script. It is
> installed in the container as a binary owned by root with the setuid
> bit, and escalates privileges to make the appropriate changes. It
> should only be used in development containers.

However when I try to do that I got

```
fixuid: already ran on this system; will not attempt to change UID/GID
```

and therefore the UID is not changed which causes a lot of problems

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the source code of `fixuid`, there is a (tiny) security for not running this binary twice (because it’s `setuid root` so it’s very dangerous):

The file [`/var/run/fixuid.ran`](https://github.com/boxboat/fixuid/blob/543e124f2951290701db419c0a4f45ab35bca556/fixuid.go#L22) is [checked](https://github.com/boxboat/fixuid/blob/543e124f2951290701db419c0a4f45ab35bca556/fixuid.go#L43) for existance before running.

Looks like someone probably run the `fixuid` binary during the boot-up phase. Maybe in an entrypoint (that may call another entrypoint and so on), or after the entrypoint when actually running the command.

`fixuid` could be used in the entrypoint **or** as a shell wrapper for the command.
If you try to do both cases, you’ll get that message.